# WPF: How to solve memory leak in this code?

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks, timer, textblock

I have a window that alert user if have any message (code bellow).
Each time `timer1.Elapsed`, the app's memory rise up more than 1 MB. After 10 alert times, it take more than 15 MB. Then if have any more alert, the used memory almost dont rise up.

I think 15 MB memory for a simple window is quite large, and maybe my app is memory leak. But I'm newbie and dont know how to solve it.
Can you help me that my code have any issues make it memory leak? Thank you very much!

**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
           FontSize="11"
           Padding="5,3,3,3">
        <Run x:Name="a_time"
             Foreground="Blue" />
        <Run x:Name="a_now"
             FontStyle="Italic" />
        <Run x:Name="a_id" />
        <LineBreak />        
        <Run x:Name="a_name"
             Foreground="Blue" />
        <Run x:Name="a_title"
             Foreground="Red"
             Tag=""
             MouseUp="a_MouseUp"
             Cursor="Hand" />
        <LineBreak />        
        <Run x:Name="a_content"
             Foreground="Gray" />
</TextBlock>
```

**Code:**

```
    List<Alert> alert_list = new List<Alert>();

    void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (alert_list.Count == 0) return;
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
        {
            this.Background = (this.Background == Brushes.Yellow) ? Brushes.LemonChiffon : Brushes.Yellow;
            Point m = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
            if ((m.X > 0 & m.X < Width & m.Y > 0 & m.Y < Height) | Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) | Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)) { showemail_tick = 1; return; }

            Alert al = alert_list[alert_list.Count - 1];
            a_title.Tag = al.e_link;
            a_time.Text = al.e_time + "    ";
            a_now.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
            a_id.Text = al.e_id;
            a_name.Text = al.e_name + "  ";
            a_title.Text = al.e_title;
            a_content.Text = al.e_content;

            alert_list.RemoveAt(alert_list.Count - 1);
        }));
    }


public class Alert
{
    public string e_time = "";
    public string e_id = "";
    public string e_link = "";
    public string e_name = "";
    public string e_title = "";
    public string e_content = "";
    public bool e_bip = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, where do you subscribe to timer1_Elapsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a memory leak, since all memory allocation and deallocation is managed by the .NET garbage collector.

What you see here is exactly the fact that the .NET garbage collector does "whatever it wants to" with memory. That is, when it doesn't need it anymore, it is totally free to still keep it for a later use it might make of it.

So you do not have to worry about this memory consumption, it does not mean that your program uses that much memory: it just means the .NET memory manager decided to keep it for himself.

It is much more easy for the programmer: you can rely on this manager to handle all the dirty work for you. Don't worry: if at some point you fall short of memory, the manager will release whatever it doesn't need. But if your system is fine and can live with the memory still being allocated to your process, then why spend time freeing it? That's what the manager does, when speaking of reasonable amounts of memory of course.

**Edit:**

That's the big leap between C-like world where you are responsible for your memory, and garbage collected world where you rely on some entity to handle the memory for you. It has advantages (you don't have anything to care about) and its drawbacks (as you mention, you can't tell exactly when the memory will be freed and so are unsure about your instantaneous memory consumption).

**Edit2:**

Mentioned in the comment, didn't know about that. You can call `System.GC.Collect()` to force the garbage collector to actually release everything it doesn't need: [doc here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.collect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx).

Although again in your case, you should let the GC do whatever it wants since it's optimized this way and it doesn't hurt your execution.

Comment: Thank for help me! After show alert, I dont use that data again. Is any way to clear that data manual?

Comment: no and you shouldn't. The data **is** cleared as far as you're concerned. It is just still in the hand of the .NET memory manager. It might decide to release it later on, or not, depending on your environment needs. So don't worry about it.

Comment: @TuyenTk There is a way to enforce the garbage collection with `GC.Collect()`. Please have a look at the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.collect%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more information. All instances which are not referenced by other instances will be cleared. But since you don't really have an issue it's not necessary to call it. The garbage collector will do it anyway.